# Working with PageObjects inside of other PageObjects using nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js, pageobjects

I'm using the last version of nightwatch I had some issues when a Page Object can have another Page Object as 'field'.

I develop PageObjects for the header, footer and for html elements related for a login action as below:

**menu.js**

```
var commands = { 
   // commands for the menu

}

module.exports = {

  elements: {
     // menu html elements selectors, i.e.
     someElementInHeader :  '.cssSelector'
  },

  commands: [commands]
}
```

**footer.js**

```
module.exports = {

  elements: {
     // footer html elements selectors
  }
}
```

But I need to embed these two Page Objects in a third Page Object, as example, a login page that contains the same menu and the same footer.

**loginPage.js**

```
// import the menu and footer js some way
module.exports = {

    url: function() {
        // get the url from configuration
        return this.api....
    }

    // should have the elements from menu and footer, along with this page elements
    elements: { ... },

    // should contain the commands from menu and some commands from the page itself
    commands: [{ ... }]
}
```

I tried to use a constructor for the loginPage Page Object, but it's not working.

Now I'm using this approach for the **loginPage.js**, but I don't think that is the better one:

```
// the header.js is a Page Object for nightwatch because it's located on the page objects path
const header = require('../common/header.js');

/**
 * commands related to this page
 */
let _commands = [];
// add comands from dependencies
_commands = _commands.concat(header.commands);

/**
 * elements related to this page
 */
let _elements = {};
// add elements from dependencies
Object.assign(_elements, header.elements);

/**
 * page object configuration
 */
module.exports = {

    url: function() {
        return this.api.globals.baseUrl + '/login';
    },

    elements: _elements,

    commands: _commands

};
```

And this is an example for tests (**simplelogin.spec.js**):

```
var customer = null;

module.exports = {

    // set tests parameters
    before : function (browser) {
        var loginPage = browser.page.pages.loginPage();

        browser
            .useCss()
            .pause(1000);

        customer = loginPage.navigate();
    },

    // check for a basic element in header is present because it's needed
    'a basic element should be present' : function (browser) {

        customer.expect.element('@someElementInHeader').to.be.present;
    },

    after : function (browser) {
        browser.end();
    }
}
```

Even though I'm reusing the code for the the header, I didn't like the design and the readibility of the code for the loginPage.js... also, if a lot of page objects is needed in this page object for further testing, it will became very verbose.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want elements that already exists in the menu and footer page objects to exist in the loginPage as well. The whole purpose of page objects is to be able to reuse the code. For example, if a selector changes for an element in the menu page object, you only have one place to go and update it. If you have this element in the loginPage as well, now you have multiple locations you need to update for the same element. I could see wanting to reuse commands from other page objects but elements doesn't make sense to have in multiple locations.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work but have you tried setting the page object inside one of the command functions in loginPage? `let menu = this.page.menuPage();` Seems like it should work but like I said I haven't tried it.

Comment: I actually just tried it and you can access a page object inside another one by using `this.api.page.pageName()`. So, it looks like you can just do `let menu = this.api.page.menu();` inside one of your command functions and then you can access the functions from the menu page object inside the login page.

Comment: @tehbeardedone I need the menu and footer Page Objects inside others page objects exactly to reuse code (the login page has different commands for the same elements from the manu page object). also, the login page is also a Page Object.

Comment: I just added more information for the question, @tehbeardedone